# react-native multiple npm warn and problems and its crash my app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, react-native-router-flux

Here I am having a little addiction problem with reaction-native since yesterday................

[image]

it completely blocks me from navigating to certain screens etc.
Here is a copy of package. json:

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.7.0",
    "jest-expo": "^22.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^22.0.2",
    "mobx-react": "^4.3.4",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "^0.49.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.18.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.23",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.19"
  }
}
```

How to install these outbuildings?
Where can I fix my problem if you've already had it, see?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't installed the dependencies in your app.  Either running

```
npm install
```

Has produced errors for those npm libraries, or it simply hasn't been run.  Try running it, and if it still doesn't work, take a look at the contents of `./npm-debug.log` for error messages related to it.

ETA: Looking closer, it seems that several of your dependencies require peers of specific versions of `react`, but you have a different version of react installed.

Are you using `react@16.0.0-beta` for a specific reason?  Things like `mobx` are looking for `react` 13/14/15/16, but not 16b.  I'd try this:

```
npm remove -S react
npm install -S react
```

and see if that works.  If you were using the React beta for a reason, you may struggle to get these to talk to each other.

Comment: I have installed my dependencies via npm install though....
where can I find npm-debug. log?

Comment: @E.D as I put, it's `./npm-debug.log` so it's in the root of the project - same level as `package.json`

Comment: Ok, thank you, that's what I thought it was, but I don't have this file. Can I generate it in some way?

Comment: nope it doesn't work and it's say : ```npm WARN react-native@0.49.5 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-beta.5 but none was installed.
```maybe it's the version of react-native ? I have generate my project with create-react-native-app but i have no reason to work with beta

Comment: Yeah, so you have an issue in that some of your dependencies require one version of React, and another requires an entirely different version of react.  You could try installing a different version of react-native, because the current version, for example, doesn't have the same requirement.  Worth noting that the React version in general is also out of date - React is 16.1.1 atm